# Is there any way to limit the number of entries a user can make?

Tags: channel-entries

I want to limit the number of entries a user can create. I've found a similar question here: [Restrict number of entries per user](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/791/restrict-number-of-entries-per-user)

The reason that answer won't work for us is because our version of EE is 2.1.3 - before safecracker was integrated. We've tried updating it to the latest version, but after three weeks encountering error after error after error we've had to roll back before we miss a deadline which could make or break our business.

Is there anyway to do this without Safecracker?

Comment: How is the user creating entries? via the control-panel or SAEF? in the template you could do a channel:entries and if total_results > x then redirect. Another approach would be a custom extension, hook on an appropriate hook (check number of database rows for author) and redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You're always better off keeping EE up to date and you'll no doubt find that the time it takes to update EE will save you even more time than trying to get current addons and solutions to work with an outdated system (by quite a long time if you're going back to 2.1.3). You can always post any errors or problems here for help.

If you're really not looking to upgrade just yet however then from what you've said and the link you provided I take it that you mean limiting entries from the front-end (i.e. Safecracker). I've got an old version of Safecracker from back in the day before it was bundled with EE (Probably about the time of EE 2.1) which may work for you but obviously this comes without support and as I mentioned you may run into problems running outdated software either now or in the future so keep it in mind. If you do want to give this a try then let me know your email.

Comment: That would be awesome - is there anyway to send you my email without posting it on here?

Comment: Email me at filter-by-proxy[at]gmail.com Strip the hyphens and replace the @.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a way to do that currently if the entries are made via the control panel. If through SAEF or Safecracker, then yes, you can definitely limit the user's entries based on a simple conditional lookup of the number of entries made by the logged in user, with the conditional restricting, for example, the entry form itself to just those that are below your prescribed maximum number of entries.  In the control panel - as GDMac indicated, you may need a custom extension to essentially perform that same lookup within the CP itself.